# Add text on path / text inside d3 arc, textPath not showing?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, d3.js

I am trying to include text inside my arc / path. I've tried with foreignObject with div, appending textPath and so on.

But I can't seem to get it right. I've tried several options, and I want the text to tilt the right way and stay within the arc.

[image]

Code:

```
    mappedArcs.forEach((event) => {
    let data = mappedItems.find((d) => d.id == event.id);

    let pathGroup = svgEl
      .append('g')
      .attr('id', 'pathGroup')
      .append('path')
      .attr('id', (i) => {
        return '#arc-label' + event.id;
      })
      .attr('d', event.arcSvg)
      .style('fill', event.colour)
      .attr('transform', 'translate(500,500)');

    pathGroup
      .style('cursor', 'pointer')
      .on('mouseover', (e) => {
        setTextValue(event.title);
        setDateValue(data.startDate + ' - ' + data.endDate);
        setShowDiv(true);
      })
      .on('mouseout', (e) => {
        setShowDiv(false);
      })
      .on('click', (e) => {
        setDataObj({
          ...dataObj,
          title: data.title,
          description: data.description,
          start: data.startDate,
          end: data.endDate,
          location: data.location,
        });
        setIsModalOpen(true);
      });

    svgEl
      .selectAll('g')
      // .attr('id', 'textGroup')
      .append('g')
      .append('text')
      .attr('x', event.centroid[0])
      .attr('y', event.centroid[2])
      .style('text-anchor', 'middle')
      .style('font', "12px 'Helvetica Neue'")
      .style('fill', 'black')
      // .append('textPath')
      .text(event.title)
      .attr('transform', 'translate(500,500)');
    // .attr('xlink:href', (d, i, j) => {
    //   return '#arc-label' + event.id;
    // });

    // svgEl
    //   .append('foreignObject')
    //   .attr('transform', 'translate(500,500)')
    // .attr('x', event.centroid[0])
    // .attr('y', event.centroid[2])
    //   .attr('width', 80)
    //   .attr('height', 80)
    //   .append('xhtml:div')
    //   .style('height', '80px')
    //   .style('width', '80px')

    //   .style('font', "12px 'Helvetica Neue'")
    //   .html(`<h3 >${event.title}</h3>`);
  });
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Start by turning yout code into a [mre], preferably even a runnable [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). That will make it easier to help you